# Set effect duration based on a css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-effects

```
$('.container').animate({ 'height': el.height()  }, { duration: 300});
```

So `el`'s height can be smaller or greater than `.container`'s height.

How can I make it so the effect duration lasts longer when the difference between the current height and the one to which I'm animating is larger?

Comment: Why do you want to? A fixed duration seems reasonable. If the duration was proportional to the height difference, it would be unbounded (i.e. large changes would take long, which isn't too user-friendly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newHeight = el.height(),
    oldHeight = $('.container').height();
$('.container').animate({height: newHeight}, Math.abs(newHeight-oldHeight)*5);
```

Change the magic constant `5` to anything that seems reasonable. You didn't provide criteria for computing the duration; you might bound it with `Math.min(/*above expression*/, maxDuration)`, or maybe it shouldn't be linear but logarithmic. You can customize it quite easily. Although that's a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(.container).height() - $(el).height() > 0)
{
    // Whatever you want to do if the container is higher than el
}
else
{
    // Other case
}
```

Not sure if it's proper JS Syntax, but it should work.

http://api.jquery.com/height/

EDIT: Nevermind, look at davin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.container').animate({height:el.height()},($(this).height()-el.height()>el.height())?3000:100);
```